# Create on QGIS a live map with WMS raster that updates constantly

Tags: qgis, wms, real-time

I have a WMS connection that allows me to use a raster map of the traffic flow that pass at some points in my city. Unfortunately the visualisation of the traffic flow is just a simple star. If you look for more info with the identify tools you see the value up and down every few minutes.

Is it possible to change the simple star visualisation? My final idea is to use this WMS to have a circle that become darker if you have more traffic at a point.

Comment: You'll need to refresh the map to get any updated image, so won't get live updates.   If you know the data source attributes you may be able to send your style (as SLD) as part of the GetMap request using either an SLD or SLD_BODY parameter